# Valores da cláusula IN como parâmetro para no subselect de uma coluna

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Preciso passar todos os valores de uma cláusula `IN`, para um `subselect` de uma coluna.

Ex:

```
SELECT   distinct
         'Atendimentos' Tipo,
         to_char(A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy') Competencia,
         pre.cd_prestador,
         se.cd_setor,
         se.nm_setor,
         (
            select  (count(distinct a2.cd_atendimento)) --* 0.3
            from    atendime a2
                    INNER JOIN PRESTADOR Pre2 ON A2.CD_PRESTADOR = 
                                         Pre2.CD_PRESTADOR
                    left join setor se2 on se2.CD_SETOR = 
                                         a2.cd_setor
            where   to_char(a2.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy') = 
                    to_char(a.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy')
                    and pre2.cd_prestador = pre.cd_prestador --Aqui é o problema
                    and se2.cd_setor = se.cd_setor
            group by to_char(A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy')
         ) total
FROM     ATENDIME A
         INNER JOIN PRESTADOR Pre ON A.CD_PRESTADOR = Pre.CD_PRESTADOR
         left join setor se on se.CD_SETOR = a.CD_SETOR
where    to_char(A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy') = '08/2018'
         and pre.cd_prestador in (127,3921,1704,28,5048,3118,130,3336,2171,1869,128,132,186)
order by se.cd_setor
```

Eu preciso que essa última coluna me traga o total geral de atendimentos. No `where` do `subselect` (coluna com o alias "total"), eu comparo a competência com a competência do `select` externo, e o setor com o setor do select externo. Até aí, tudo normal. O problema é o prestador, que, caso fosse só um, bastava ficar dessa forma que está aí em cima. Porém, preciso que a comparação seja feita com todos os valores que são passados na cláusula `IN` do select externo.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Sua edição para imagem do código empobrecia a publicação, portanto apenas formatei e identei sua `query`

Comment: Se eu entendi o problema bastaria trocar no subselect o cd_prestador = por uma replicação do "in" ... o agregador será pelo total.

Comment: Sim. Fazendo a consulta em um editor, funcionaria. Mas a consulta vai pra um relatório, não pode ficar com esses números fixos.

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/289781-concatenar-valores/?do=findComment&comment=1053697     veja se ajuda ... mas seu problema é o mesmo com uma só consulta...

Answer (score 0):

Talvez assim?

```
SELECT      DISTINCT 'Atendimentos'                 AS Tipo
        ,   TO_CHAR(A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy')    AS Competencia
        ,   PRE.CD_PRESTADOR
        ,   SE.CD_SETOR
        ,   SE.NM_SETOR
        ,   NVL(X.Contador, 0)                      AS Total
FROM        ATENDIME    A
INNER JOIN  PRESTADOR   PRE ON A.CD_PRESTADOR   = PRE.CD_PRESTADOR
LEFT JOIN   SETOR       SE  ON SE.CD_SETOR      = A.CD_SETOR
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      PRE.CD_PRESTADOR
                        ,   SE.CD_SETOR
                        ,   TO_CHAR(A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy')    AS Data
                        ,   COUNT(DISTINCT A.CD_ATENDIMENTO)        AS Contador
                FROM        ATENDIME    A
                INNER JOIN  PRESTADOR   PRE     ON A.CD_PRESTADOR   = PRE.CD_PRESTADOR
                LEFT JOIN   SETOR       SE      ON SE.CD_SETOR      = A.CD_SETOR
                GROUP BY    PRE.CD_PRESTADOR
                        ,   SE.CD_SETOR
                        ,   TO_CHAR(A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy')
            ) X             ON  X.CD_PRESTADOR  = A.CD_PRESTADOR
                            AND X.CD_SETOR      = SE.CD_SETOR
                            AND X.Data          = TO_CHAR(A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy')
WHERE       TO_CHAR(A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'mm/yyyy') = '08/2018'
        AND PRE.CD_PRESTADOR IN (127, 3921, 1704, 28, 5048, 3118, 130, 3336, 2171, 1869, 128, 132, 186)
ORDER BY    SE.CD_SETOR
```